# How I can make $\Bbb{C}[x]$ into a Banach algebra?

Tags: reference-request, banach-algebras

Let $\Bbb{C}$ the complex field. Define  $\Bbb{C}[x]$ as the set of all polynomials with variable $x$. It is known that $\Bbb{C}[x]$ is a algebra. Now the question is this that how I can make it a Banach algebra?Any reference?

Comment: Why do you think you can make it into a Banach algebra?

Comment: I don't know! But it can be normed algebra

Comment: You can't! Unless of course you identify it with a dense subset of $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: Are you really asking how to make ${\mathbf C}[x]$ itself into a Banach algebra, or what its *completion* under some specific norm looks like as a Banach algebra?

Comment: Yes it's completion

Comment: Pick any element of any Banach algebra. That induces a map from $\mathbb{C}[x]$ into that algebra. Take the completion of the image.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: It will define an algebra homomorphism, but to make a completion one needs a monomorphism. I do not think David asked about factor-algebras.